# Django Scripts run every migration

Tags: mysql, django, triggers, migration

We are using triggers to capture every modification to a table for SOX compliance. the question is as we upgrade our model, we continually have to drop and recreate triggers.

we now have a bunch of sql scripts that are duplicated with minor changes.

~here is the question: is there a hook, or some type of "run this every migration" or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of signals like pre_syncdb or post_migrate that you can use. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-syncdb

Comment: LOL! sorry I forgot I asked this question! thanks, looking into this now